# angular laravel unauthorized 401 error

Tags: angular, laravel, jwt

Okay, I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I really tried everything.
In agular I just send user data to sign up

```
signUp(userData: LoginData) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.rootPath}api/signup`, userData);
  }
```

On backend

```
public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or password doesn\'t exist'],
                401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    public function signup(signUp $request)
    {
        User::create($request->all());
        return $this->login();
    }
```

signUp

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

It adds new user to database, but I ALWAYS get 401 error which says user is not authorized. It is strange and I can't unerstand what am I doing wrong...
Field REMEMBER_TOKEN is null, but I think it is not the problem...

Comment: Are you getting your request data on Laravel side?

Comment: Can you paste your route definition? Make sure your route is not in the api routes file as you cannot set session data on those routes. If it is, try moving the route to the web routes file.

Comment: But I use laravel as api for angular, so I think routes should be as api...

Comment: I tried to see the value of credentials and they are absolutely okay, so now I am even more puzzled than before. Everythoin seems to be okay, but it doesn't work...

Comment: I also see that my passwords in database are not encrypted (they are as user write them when sign in) May this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add info in case it is useful for other people. I have fixed the issue that is related to this.
I am working in Angular 7, and Laravel 5.7 as API REST. In angular I created an interceptor in order to add the headers 'automatically'. 
And then, I've created the API for private routes and also experienced these issues described above.
POSTMAN and Advanced REST worked well, the problem were the requests by Angular. 
And now, I've added the headers manually in each HTTP request as follows;

//Example for 'GET' request

```
userLogOut(): Observable<any[]> {
    let parameters = new HttpHeaders();
    parameters = parameters.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.session.getToken());
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.usersUrl + 'logout', { headers: parameters });
}
```

//Example for 'POST' request

```
userLogOut(): Observable<any[]> {
    let parameters = new HttpHeaders();
    parameters = parameters.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.session.getToken() );
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.usersUrl + 'logout', '', { headers: parameters } );
}
```

Both of them work well.
Don't forget to add this at your constructor

```
private http: HttpClient
```

and

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Hope it helps!